# How often can I do a data export

Tags: data-export

I wanted to test the data export functionality and I created an export of a small amount of data.  After figuring out exactly what I wanted to do, I went back to the export page and the "Export Now" button is grayed out.
Is there a time limit on how often you can "Export Now"?  Anyway to reset it so I can do the full export I need?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Refer to Help and Training: https://help.salesforce.com/htviewhelpdoc?err=1&id=admin_exportdata.htm&siteLang=en_US

Frequency of export depends on your Edition:

> Weekly export available in: Enterprise, Performance, and Unlimited
>   Editions Monthly export available in: All editions, except for
>   Database.com

Exports can be manual or automatic:

> You can generate backup files manually once every six days (for weekly
>   export) or 28 days (for monthly export). You can also schedule backup
>   files to generate automatically at weekly or monthly intervals.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  I missed that when I read the documentation.  Wish I read that before I did my test export!